# jquery ajax requests are not responding on the new tab after the php form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Hi  i am submitting a form using php on form submit click i am opening a new window using jquery.

after opening the window the php form is submitted on that page but it takes 5 to 10 min depending on the file sizes because i am processing file data after uploading the files on my localhost which the users uploads and in the new tab i want to show the processed data progress using jquery ajax but on the new window tab the ajax requests are being sent but they are not being sent to the server in the chrome network tab if i click on the sent request it shows me this

> provisional headers are shown

means the server is not returning any response.

but after the form is submission is completed and files data is processed then the jquery ajax request are returning me the status 200k and the response

Here is my form submission new window open code using jqyery

```
 $(".btnDataMigrate").click(function (e) {
                var fileName = $("#filesToUpload").val();
                var path = $(this).attr("data-popupUrl")
                    if(fileName) { 
                        window.open(path,'Data Migrate Files Upload Status','width=800,height=800');
                    } else { // no file was selected
                    }

            });
```

Here is the jquery ajax request code

```
 function fetch_files_progess(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:base_path()+'/data_migration/fetch_completed_files',
                data:{},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){


                    $('#notice').html(response.result);


                },
               error: function(response){
               }
            });


        }

fetch_files_progess();
setInterval(function(){fetch_files_progess();}, 9000);
```

Kindly help me how i can get the response from the jquery ajax request during the form submission process.

Also if the open the other localhost page then also dont open until the form submission is in process.

Actually i want to the completed process files status on the new tabs during the php form submission.That is why i am using jquery ajax on the new tab to find the processed file status.
I am on xampp localhost.

Thanks

Comment: If you are posting a large file then you need to increase server response time to a request. You need to increase POST size, request time out and keep alive time.

Comment: @AfshanShujat The file size are between 50kb to 2 MB and i am setting the php set_time_limit to 0 the files are submitting and being prcoessed successfully the main problem is that i can not send ajax request on other pages during the form submission of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the server side was still processing the request. If we are using something like PHP or ASP with session data, the session data is locked until the ajax has finished. So, to allow the user to continue browsing the website, you have to call **session_write_close().** This saves the session and unlocks it so that other pages waiting to continue will proceed. Without this, several pages can be waiting for the lock to be removed.

using **session_write_close().** has solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should use some recipe like explained in this [**`Sitepoint post`**](https://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/)

You should make AJAX request from time to time and get `$_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"]` and `$_SESSION[$key]["content_length"]` from session. And correctly show it.

Comment: i dont want to track the file uploading.I want to keep track of how much of my uploaded file is processed the main issues i am getting here that my server is not responding to any of my jquery ajax request during the file upload and file processing when i click on form submit

Comment: I guess, you have wrong settings on webserver. Do you use Apache or Nginx? Take a look on settings like MaxClients or MaxRequests

Comment: i am using Apache okay let me look into it.

Comment: i have run phpinfo() it shows me this
Max Requests Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
(is this setting of my Max Requests is right)...?
but i could not find MaxClients can you please tell me where i can find MaxClients in php i have also looked it in file httpd.config

Comment: i have read this post but i could not find any MaxClients could you please tell me how can i find it i am using php 5.6 xampp

Comment: i have find the <IfModule mpm_prefork_module> and its values in the httpd-mpm.conf  file in appache folder but i could not find the MaxClients  clients value can you please help me on this